# Average complexity of random-pick comparison sort

Tags: probability, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, sorting

> **Motivation.** Suppose we have a number of images that we want to arrange in a linear order from the prettiest to the ugliest. At our disposal we have a trained aesthete, whom we can show two pictures and ask him which is the prettiest. We assume that the aesthete's preferences are unchanging and internally consistent. (That's a pretty big assumption, but this is mathematics: Our assumptions don't have to be likely, only consistent).
>
> Our task is to discover the true aesthetic order between the images without paying the aesthete for too much work. Ideally we would use a good close-to-minimal comparison sorting algorithm, such as binary insertion sort which comes within $n$ of the information-theoretic bound of $\log_2 n!$ comparisons.
>
> Unfortunately most of the algorithms at hand tend to ask the aesthete runs of questions where he's asked to compare the same image to several other images in succession, and he finds that so boring that he threatens to increase his rates. While we're trying to find a better algorithm, the junior member of the design team suggests just to ask random questions until we know enough (but avoiding questions that we can deduce the answer to already). Is this a good idea?

**Actual question**. Given $n$, let $R_0$ be the identity relation on $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. As long as $R_k$ is not a total order, choose $(a,b)$ uniformly in $\{(a,b) \mid 1\le a<b\le n\}\setminus R_k$, and let $R_{k+1}$ be the transitive closure of $R_k\cup\{(a,b)\}$.

What is the expected number of steps until $R_k$ is a total order?

The ideal answer would give an explicit (and feasible) way to compute it, but just the asymptotic behavior would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is partial -- it's what I get from Obinna's ideas up until the point where I cannot follow his reasoning anymore. *(Parts of it are wrong; I'm leaving them here as examples of something that doesn't work).*

We can reformulate the problem as:

> Process the edges $\{(a,b)\mid 1\le a < b \le n\}$ in a (uniformly chosen) random order. Whenever an edge is *not* in the transitive closure of the edges considered so far, it corresponds to a question that needs to be asked. What is the expected number of questions to be asked?

This reformulation corresponds to excluding edges that *are* in the transitive closure *lazily* when our random choice hits them, instead of before each choice. At each time the next question *actually* asked always still ends up being chosen uniformly among the questions it makes sense to ask at any given step, so the reformulation doesn't change the possible question sequences or their probability.

By additivity of expectations, the expected number of questions asks is simply the sum over all possible edges of the probability that this edge becomes a question during a run of the algorithm.

For the edge $(i,j)$, whether it becomes a question depends on which edges $(a,b)$ with $i\le a < b \le j$ have been considered *before* $(i,j)$. Edges with ends before $i$ or after $j$ don't matter, and one sees that the probability depends only on the distance between $i$ and $j$.

Let $f(k)$ be the probability that, <s>in random graph on the vertices $\{1,2,3,\ldots k\}$ where each possible edge appears with probability $1/2$, there's no strictly increasing path from $1$ to $k$ containing at least $2$ edges.</s>

The probability that edge $(i,j)$ becomes a question is then $f(j-i+1)$, <s>because every *other* edge is equally likely to be considered before $(i,j)$ or after it</s> *(whoops, no. The probability of each edge being in the graph is $1/2$, but the edges are not independent)*. And the answer we're looking for is
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} f(j-i+1) = \sum_{k=2}^n (n-k+1)f(k) $$

Obinna's answer appears to conclude (using an analogy I can't follow) that $f(k)=2/k$. <s>However, that can't be right, because there are $2^{k(k-1)/2}$ equally probable random graphs being considered in the above definition of $f(k)$, so $f(k)$ is surely some multiple of $2^{-k(k-1)/2}$. And that can't possibly be $2/k$ when $k$ is not a power of $2$.</s>

I can't find an expression for $f(k)$, though. <s>(I have a dynamic programming algorithm to compute $f(2)$ up to $f(k)$ in $O(k^2)$ time, but it's not immediately enlightening).</s>

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. I was actually thinking of the problem a little differently though. My thought process was, "what if we already know that the pairs are at a distance of $m$ apart? How will this affect the number of steps?". We know that if they are at a distance $1$ apart, our algorithm must pick it (otherwise we can't form a Hamiltonian path). This adds $(n-1)$ steps to our number of steps. The reasoning for the other cases is also similar.

Comment: @obinna: My problem here is that if my reasoning here works, then the eventual answer will always be a dyadic rational (i.e. an integer multiple of some negative power of 2), and your result with harmonic numbers isn't of that form. So something must be wrong somewhere, and I think it's your rather handwavy appeal to resistor networks.

Comment: What's the recurrence for the dynamic programming algorithm you mentioned?

Comment: Something feels wrong with this argument.  For instance, the probability that the 'question' $(4,5)$ is considered over the course of sorting the integers $1\ldots10$ must be $1$; no comparisons with other numbers are of any help in deciding their relative order.  By contrast, the question $(4, 6)$ won't necessarily be considered if both $(4, 5)$ and $(5, 6)$ have been.  I may well be missing it, but I don't see how the random-graph model with equal edge probabilities is relevant.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Yes, $(4,5)$ is always considered, which is reflected by $f(2)=1$. (A random graph on $\{1,2\}$ _always_ has no increasing path from $1$ to $2$ of length $\ge 2$). On the other hand $f(3)=3/4$, as a random graph on $\{1,2,3\}$ has an increasing path from $1$ to $3$ of length $\ge 2$ with probability $1/4$. Thus $(4,6)$ will be asked with probability $3/4$.

Comment: We can show that there are $2^{n-2}-1$ such paths.

Comment: @obinna: Knowing how many paths there are in the complete graph is not enough, because many of the paths will share edges, and then their appearances are not independent.

Comment: Yes. It was simply a comment. I still believe that there is an interpretation of this problem using electric circuits (or network flows) that makes it much easier. I have come across similar problems like this that may seem almost intractable but become shockingly easy when thought of as a network of some sort.

Comment: @HenningMakholm For the original problem, in the $n=3$ case, I seem to get a $\frac23$ probability that the edge $(1,3)$ is considered: there's a $\frac13$ probability that our first comparison is $(1,3)$; a $\frac13\cdot\frac12$ probability that our first two comparisons are $(1,2)$ and then $(1,3)$; and a $\frac13\cdot\frac12$ probability that the first two comparisons are $(2,3)$ and then $(1,3)$.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Steven: You're right. My mistake was that even though the probability that _any given_ edge has been considered before the one we're looking at is $1/2$, these probabilities are _not independent_.

Comment: Actually, we can think about this problem in a slightly different way. Instead of asking the question - "What is the probability that we have an increasing sequence?". We can simply disregard all edges going directly to $k$ (assume we already choose them) and ask the question-what is the probability that we have an increasing sub-sequence to any of the other vertices?. For each vertex, we can keep removing edges and keep asking this question and for us to stop we must have no edges left.

Comment: It stands to reason that we are just as likely to end up in any of the $(k - 1)$ vertices as our last vertex.

Comment: @obinna: I'm completely lost in your last two comments. What do you mean by "end up" here?

Comment: I mean the last vertex from which we can't make any other choices. i.e. removing all edges makes it a single vertex.

Comment: @obinna: Nope, still completely lost. How do you get from my problem to a formulation where it makes any sense to speak about a "vertex from which we can't make any other choices"? And if so, please make that formulation explicit instead of just assuming that I already know what it is.

Comment: I'm assuming the initial formulation where we have a directed edge from every number in ${1,2,3,...,k}$ to all numbers strictly larger than itself. The numbers are the labels of the vertices. We randomly choose the edges and we want to know the probability that we have a strictly increasing path from $1$ to $k$.

Comment: @obinna: What does that have to do with any concept of "vertex from which we can't make any other choices"? In my understanding there's no concept of any choice being made "at/from a particular vertex". The only choice in the initial formulation is a _global_ choice of an edge to consider in each step, but this choice is not made "at/from" any particular vertex.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong then. I was thinking of the random variable $X_{ij}$ which I defined earlier and I'm trying to answer the question, what is the probability that we don't have a strictly increasing sub-sequence from $i$ to $j$ (in our random choices so far).

Comment: @obinna: Um... do we agree that all that matters is _which_ edges have been considered before $(i,j)$ comes up, not the _order_ in which they where chosen? You seem to stop making sense to me at more or less exactly the same point each time you try to explain.

Comment: Yes. All that matters is whether there is already a path or not.

Comment: @obinna: Then I'm as confused as ever.